# How do I activate foreign keys in C, using sqlite?

Tags: c, sqlite, foreign-keys

I need to use foreign keys at my program, but I don´t know how to activate this PRAGMA using C Language. (I wanna use CASCADE modes.)

With sqlite binary, I just write **PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;** and it works.

My question is: How I can do this in C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In part, the [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) manual says:

> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be compiled with neither SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined. If SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER is defined but SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY is not, then SQLite behaves as it did prior to version 3.6.19 - foreign key definitions are parsed and may be queried using PRAGMA foreign_key_list, but foreign key constraints are not enforced. The PRAGMA foreign_keys command is a no-op in this configuration. If OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY is defined, then foreign key definitions cannot even be parsed (attempting to specify a foreign key definition is a syntax error).
>
> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled, it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the PRAGMA foreign_keys command. For example:
>
> ```
> sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```
>
> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection separately. (Note, however, that future releases of SQLite might change so that foreign key constraints enabled by default. Careful developers will not make any assumptions about whether or not foreign keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable them as necessary.) The application can can also use a PRAGMA foreign_keys statement to determine if foreign keys are currently enabled.

And the page about [pragmas](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) says:

> - Specific pragma statements may be removed and others added in future releases of SQLite. There is no guarantee of backwards compatibility.
> - No error messages are generated if an unknown pragma is issued. Unknown pragmas are simply ignored. This means if there is a typo in a pragma statement the library does not inform the user of the fact.
> - Some pragmas take effect during the SQL compilation stage, not the execution stage. This means if using the C-language sqlite3_prepare(), sqlite3_step(), sqlite3_finalize() API (or similar in a wrapper interface), the pragma may run during the sqlite3_prepare() call, not during the sqlite3_step() call as normal SQL statements do. Or the pragma might run during sqlite3_step() just like normal SQL statements. Whether or not the pragma runs during sqlite3_prepare() or sqlite3_step() depends on the pragma and on the specific release of SQLite.

So, you prepare the PRAGMA statement - and execute it to make sure it takes effect.

There might be a more specialized API; you can read the manual too.

Comment: Thanks, but tried: sqlite3_prepare(db, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;", -1, &stmt, 0); sqlite3_step(stmt); The step results SQLITE_DONE, but it is not working yet the foreign key..

Comment: Did you check how your SQLite library was built?  Note the requirements in the first quote - you have to build SQLite to allow foreign keys to be enabled.

Comment: IT'S WORKING!! I don't know why, but I changed the PC to make a compile test and there is working!! Very thanks, man! I appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

C is exactly the same — simply execute the statement `"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"`.

Comment: OK, but how? sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", NULL, NULL, NULL); Don't work

Comment: Well, "don't work" could mean many things. You should check for errors after every call to SQLite APIs. Do you get an error at any point? If not, how do you know it does not work?

Comment: Sorry.. The return is SQLITE_OK, but I spoke that because I am making the C code together with another sample test at sqlite>. So, first I execute the  sql CREATE TABLE at C function, then I use the same sql to do the same thing, and then I execute others querys.. When I try to change one value at foreign table (UPDATE), in C program nothing is happening and at sqlite, all values at main table changes. (sorry my english, I'm brazilian)

Comment: PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
CREATE TABLE table1(table1id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE table2(num INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, table1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 REFERENCES table1(table1id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (0,'Default');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'name1');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2000,1);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2001,1);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2002,1);
SELECT * FROM table2;
UPDATE table1 SET table1id = 2 WHERE name = 'name1';
SELECT * FROM table2;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name = 'name1';
SELECT * FROM table2;

Comment: It seems like it should work. The pragma works in my own application.

Comment: In my sqlite application works too, but in C application not.. =/ but thank you for attention!! If you have other idea, I'll be grateful

Comment: IT'S WORKING!! I don't know why, but I changed the PC to make a compile test and there is working!! Very thanks, man! I appreciate